# Rewrite Url at my website but my index on sub folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've been crawling forums for about 2 hours and still haven't found the solution to my problem so I am turning to you guys for help.

My URL looks like this
http://sevalinmutfagi.com/list.php?id=1?kategori=borekler
I want it to look like this
http://sevalinmutfagi.com/tarifler/borekler

I try so much rewrite example but my index file at a subfolder in /View/ so I can't rewrite my URLs

here my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?sevalinmutfagi.com$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/View/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /View/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?sevalinmutfagi.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ View/index.php [L]
```

This code works well for redirect subfolder all pages but I try to add rewrite URL codes can't work. I hope that has been revealing. Thanks to every for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's worked for me fine.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I tried this code "RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,2})/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ list.php?id=$1&kategori=$2 [QSA]" but nothing change i think nothing happen cuz my index at sub folder what are you thinking guys ?

Answer (score 1):

The FIRST thing to learn about `mod_rewrite` is when NOT to use it. Since `mod_alias` handles your specific task very nicely, that’s what I’d use:

```
Redirect 301 / /subfolder/
```

Since that looks like it would be “loopy,” you could fall back on mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subfolder/
RewriteRule .? subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

There’s just too much wrong with your attempt to cover … and I’ve addressed exactly those issues many times in many threads. Therefore, you might benefit from reading the `mod_rewrite` tutorial linked in my signature as it contains explanations and sample code. It’s helped may members and should help you, too